# Who are the people referenced in “You Don't Belong” by Bad Religion?

Tags: song-lyrics, bad-religion

The song ["You Don't Belong" by Bad Religion](https://www.badreligion.com/albums/13/The_Process_Of_Belief) obviously references the SoCal punk scene they were a part of. In it, a number of people are mentioned by name.

> Missy was a teen blue video star,
> Tom took his life in his mother's car,
> Milo went to college but you knew about that,
> Todney played our records,
> Jimmy<sup>†</sup> started riots,
> Laurie was always quiet,
> she was battling depression
>
> (...)
>
> Jack wore a skirt but he knew how to scrap,
> Billy went to county on a class one possession,
> Wendy went to school while her daddy shot smack,
> Eugene kept a list,
> Mugger was security,
> Mary she kept her purity,
> we were all in it together
>
> —"You Don't Belong" by Bad Religion, [lyrics from their homepage](https://www.badreligion.com/albums/13/The_Process_Of_Belief)

**Who are they?**

Some are obvious, like [Milo who went to college](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milo_Goes_to_College) or [Rodney who played their records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodney_on_the_ROQ), but is it known who the others are?

Has the band ever talked about it in interviews?

---

I saw some speculation on [a discussion board](https://www.thebrpage.net/discography/song.asp?songName=You+Don%27t+Belong):

- Missy — ?
- Tom — Tom Clement, known from "I Give You Nothing"
- Milo — Milo Aukerman, from the Descendents
- Rodney — Rodney on the ROQ
- Jimmy<sup>†</sup> — ?
- Laurie — possibly Laurie Anderson
- Jack — Jack Grisham, from TSOL
- Billy — Brett Gurewitz himself
- Wendy — ?
- Eugene — ?
- Mugger — a roadie for Black Flag
- Mary — ?

---

<sup>†: The lyrics on their official homepage have him as Jimmy, but a number of other sources have him as GG, referring to either Black Flag guitarist Greg Ginn or New York punk icon GG Allin.</sup>

---

*[I've asked this question over on the Music Fans Stack](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/2169/137), but didn't get a satisfactory answer. So I'm giving it a shot over here.*